# I want to sum specific cells from multiple worksheets inside and array formula

Tags: arrays, excel, worksheet

This is the formula I'm using to get the value of an indirectly referenced cell in another worksheet:

=OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&SheetName"'!$A$1");Row;Col)*BooleanValue

As you can see I add a specific cell (referenced Row and Col) from the also referenced SheetName and then, that value is multiplied by 1 or 0. This is needed because the need to add a specific worksheet changes.

When extending this to more than one worksheet, I copied and added this same formula 10 times for the 10 Sheets I need to take in account, but the formula becomes too long and difficult to read or edit and being used to array formulas I think there is surely a better way but I don't know how to do it.

In the forum I've seen solutions to filter the cells in different to be added but I don't see the way to adapt them to my situation as I sum the cells from 10 worksheets and multiply them by an array of boolean values.

Thank you very much in advance for any help.
Enrique

Comment: You may have to pull cell values from the different sheets into individual cells in a "work in progress" sheet, then apply your longer formula to those (now local) cells.

Comment: That would be one solution, yes. I was trying to make it more efficiently as the number of cells is quite big. Thanks in any case for your feedback.